# How to Save uid and fcm token in firebase swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am having trouble saving the user uid along with the fcm token. I saved the fcm token successfully but cannot save the uid. I would like to save the uid after the user signs up, the token is already saved when a user opens the app.

Here is my current code:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
     messaging.token { token, _ in
         guard let token = token else{
            
            return
         }
            
        let tokens = [
            token,
            Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        ]
        let key = self.ref.childByAutoId().child("Uid").key
        
        self.ref.child(key!).setValue(tokens)
        
        print("Token: \(token )")
     }
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("token")
    let Uid =  Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
     
 }
    
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
```

---

Edit

This is what my firebase currently looks like

```
  "token": {
    "-N6tIuKBUkFpzhrEdX6f": [
      "cs00XevXU0WDsT2z-yginY:APA91bED3KwXRC9dXJN0iJECZu2todoD0cAO9mw_3vx3nd7WLIEkA3UkCWU4GMy5zt1iHOkOvN4OGgVZuBq12WC9LJ3o0QZyB88Rn01z7_kLdoh1ul0_opbTE-IrcZ3ylGaYuLovSfHe"
    ]
}
```

This is where I want to store the uid, and what I want it to look like:

```
  "Token1": {
    "Token": "SomeTokenValue",
    "UID": "SomeUID"
  }
```

Comment: Can you please what is your firebase schema look like, and where exactly do you want to store uid?